# How to use target encoding : expanding mean on the test set

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, deep-learning, target, categorical-data

The `expanding mean` is a way to prevent overfitting when performing `target encoding`. But what I do not understand is how to use this technic to apply a fit on the train set and a transform on the test set to encode my features, as this encoding technic encode the features dynamically; the encoding value for a given feature level is varying input after input as it depends from a cumulative sum.

```py
cumulative_sum = training.groupby(column)["target"].cumsum() - training["target"]
cumulative_count = training.groupby(column).cumcount()
train_new[column + "_mean_target"] = cumulative_sum/cumulative_count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you simply map the mean values of the target variable calculated for different categories to the corresponding categories in your test set? The cumulative means are needed only for the training part for regularization purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would also be interested to know how to compute the mean encoding for the test set.
For now, I am recomputing the mean over the train set and assigning the values to the test set.

```
test.merge(training.groupby(column).mean().reset_index(), on=column)
```